# Что нужно задать в переменную "n", чтобы при вводе любых неправильных ответов выводилось "не правильный ответ"

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, if, операторы

```
print("Загадка: Представь, что ты падаешь в яму полную ядовитых змей. Как выжить?")
n = input("Ваш ответ: ").lower()
print(n)

if n == ' ': #Вот в эти кавычки, что нужно написать, чтобы при вводе любых ответов выводился print
    print('Правильный ответ: Перестать воображать')
    
elif n == 'перестать воображать':
    print('Ответ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ!')
```

Comment: `if not n == 'перестать воображать':`

Answer (score 1):

**вариант 1:**

```
if n == 'перестать воображать':
    print('Ответ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ!')
else:
    print('Правильный ответ: Перестать воображать')
```

**вариант 2:**

```
if n != 'перестать воображать':
    print('Правильный ответ: Перестать воображать')
else:
    print('Ответ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ!')
```

Comment: спасибо большое!